# JBoss AS 7.1.1 and dynamic filter instance registration

Tags: java, jboss7.x, servlet-3.0

In our web application we need to register preconfigured instances of filters dynamically using `ServletContext#addFilter(String filterName, Filter filter)`. Some filters may not have default constructor.
It works perfectly on Tomcat (8.5.24) but some of our clients use JBoss AS 7.1.1 on which we faced the following issue:

```
Exception starting filter myFilter: java.lang.InstantiationException: our.company.MyFilter
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:368) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:80) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:441) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
```

It seems that JBoss tries to instantiate the filter despite of the fact that it was already been instantiated during registration proccess. Finally it fails because of absence of default constructor in `our.company.MyFilter`. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Yes, declare a default constructor :) (Just have a look at the [source](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/11.0.0.Final/web-common/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/web/common/WebInjectionContainer.java)

Comment: @m4gic Of course I know that if I add default constructor JBoss will be able to instantiate my filter. The question is why is it even doing it? It seems like a bug for me.